# Generate routes with the post method using the rails controller generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controllers, http-method

Is their a way to specify the method for an action when generating a controller in rails 4? I don't want to generate all the routes with the `get` method.
As an example the following

```
rails g controller sessions new signin
```

will generate the routes

```
get 'sessions/new'
get 'sessions/signin'
```

but I want that the signin action will be a `POST` action

```
post 'sessions/signin'
```

is that possible with the generator?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see there is nothing in the Rails code that implements your requested feature.

The [`controller_generator.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08754f12e65a9ec79633a605e986d0f1ffa4b251/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/controller/controller_generator.rb) implements the controller generator of the command line.
The code which generates the routes is pretty short and contains nothing you requested:

```
    # This method creates nested route entry for namespaced resources.
    # For eg. rails g controller foo/bar/baz index
    # Will generate -
    # namespace :foo do
    #   namespace :bar do
    #     get 'baz/index'
    #   end
    # end
    def generate_routing_code(action)
      depth = regular_class_path.length
      # Create 'namespace' ladder
      # namespace :foo do
      #   namespace :bar do
      namespace_ladder = regular_class_path.each_with_index.map do |ns, i|
        indent("namespace :#{ns} do\n", i * 2)
      end.join

      # Create route
      #     get 'baz/index'
      route = indent(%{get '#{file_name}/#{action}'\n}, depth * 2)

      # Create `end` ladder
      #   end
      # end
      end_ladder = (1..depth).reverse_each.map do |i|
        indent("end\n", i * 2)
      end.join

      # Combine the 3 parts to generate complete route entry
      namespace_ladder + route + end_ladder
    end
```

Basically it just creates a `get` route for every passed action and provides no more functionality.

**Either way you can change the `routes.rb` by hand after creating the controller.**

Comment: I was thinking, that it might be good to be able to specify for the generator what's the method to use for each action, like for example: `signin:post new:get` or make `get` the default but explicitly specify any method else, I think this is not a complex feature to add, so I am wondering why it is messing?

Comment: Maybe because one can easily change all that in the `routes.rb`, while it would be pretty complicated to invent an easy syntax for that on the command line?